# DatetTime.ParseExact() method does not exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I would like to use the ParseExact Method from a DateTime Object as I did many times before... (It's my first time using C# in ASP.NET)

But the ParseExact Method is just not existing...

I would like to do something like this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy", provider);
```

But the only options I get is:

```
DateTime.Equals
DateTime.ReferenceEyuals
DateTime.CreateHtmlTextWritersFromType
```

I just don't get why?

Comment: What framework version are you referencing?

Comment: @CodeCaster .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: Is `DateTime` the name of a member on your page, for example a control?

Comment: The method `CreateHtmlTextWriterFromType` is from the `Page` class.

Comment: And be aware, `mm` specifier is for minutes but `MM` specifier is for months.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably have another class also called "DateTime" somewhere. You can verify this by using the full namespace:

```
System.DateTime dt = System.DateTime.ParseExact(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy", provider);
```

Comment: Wow I should have seen that myself... Thanks alot!